# sequelize find on login retrives always sucess

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I am trying to do a simple login using nodejs and sequelize, i already have a user on the database and i try to send the info as req.body and checking if it exist in the where clausure

Like this:

```
router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log("hi");
  if (JSON.stringify(req.body) == "{}") {
    return res.status(400).json({ Error: "Login request body is empty" });
  }
  if (!req.body.username || !req.body.password) {
    return res.status(400).json({ Error: "Missing fields for login" });
  }
  User.find({ where: { username: req.body.username,password: req.body.password} })
    .then(function (user) {
      return res.status(200).json({ message: "loged in!" });
    }).catch(function (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({ Error: "There is no user with those fields" });
    });
});
```

it enters always on the loged in message, even if i send data that doesn't exist on the database, any info why it is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if `user` is actually defined:

```
User.find({ where: { username: req.body.username,password: req.body.password} })
    .then(function (user) {
      if (! user) {
        return res.status(400).json({ Error: "There is no user with those fields" });
      } else {
        return res.status(200).json({ message: "loged in!" });
      }
    })
    .catch(...)
```

You're assuming that a query that doesn't yield any results will throw an error, but it won't (because the query ran successfully).

Comment: you are absolutly right :), i think the else is not needed since you have the return statement

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can make unique index on db to be completely sure that user is unique.
Btw, this index will speed-up login process.

[Sequelize index docs ref](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html#indexes)